# Send language layout from USB HID keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb, avr, hid

I am currently working on a USB HID keyboard using an Atmel microcontroller. Everything is working fine but I usually use different keyboard layouts on different machines. Now I started wondering if it would be possible to tell the host which keyboard layout to use, i.e. EN-US, so that keycodes will always get mapped on the right character on every machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

USB keyboards send keycodes that represent physical position of key on the keyboard, not the ascii/unicode key data.  This is probably a bad thing in term of localization, but this is a protocol from the 90's, they wanted to keep things simple, and keep the mindset of the PC/AT standard of the time.

Problem with this approach is hardware cannot enforce the layout that is printed on its physical buttons. All it can do is hint the driver about its mapping. [USB HID](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf) defines a `bCountryCode` field in the USB descriptor data (§ 6.2.1, p. 22) to this extent:

> Numeric expression identifying country code of the localized hardware.

Unfortunately, this is underspecified (no distinction among variants of keyboards for the same language, etc.), so hardware manufacturers never used this field much, they nearly always put `0x00`, i.e. `NotSupported`.  Because hardware never used this much, OS support was never developed.

Comment: An exception is Solaris with Sun/Oracle keyboards which have dip switches to tell their layout to the driver. See https://deskthority.net/wiki/Sun_Type_7#Dip_switches

Answer (score 1):

A USB keyboard usually does not have a notion of "keyboard layout". Keys in the same place on all keyboards will send he same make/break codes no matter what the layout (EN, DE, etc.). It is the task of a keyboard driver within the host to provide correct translation tables (--> keyboard driver) from scan code to char/fuction.

So you may need 2 or more translation tables in your micro and think of a way how to command your micro to select the correct one.

[further reading](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html)

Comment: a hardware switch (e.g. dip switch using 2-3 ports) where 2/4/8 layouts can be coded, or a special key combination (Windows uses {Left-ALT} + {Shift} that your software interprets and reacts on ...